# Usar Select Distinct con Order by

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

tengo esta consulta sencilla:

```
SELECT 
    vw_load.patient_code, ROUND(vw_load.val::numeric,4) AS value, vw_load.time::DATE AS date
FROM 
    vw_load 
WHERE 
    vw_load.disease = 8
AND 
    vw_load.time >= '2023-01-01' AND vw_load.time <= '2023-03-09'
AND 
    vw_load.patient_code = '50006A02300001'
ORDER BY wv_load.time
```

Como me salen valores duplicados hago un distinct del campo value con lo que obtengo un resultado sin duplicados:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ROUND(vw_load.val::numeric,4) AS value, vw_load.patient_code,  vw_load.time::DATE AS date
FROM 
    vw_load 
WHERE 
    vw_load.disease = 8
AND 
    vw_load.time >= '2023-01-01' AND vw_load.time <= '2023-03-09'
AND 
    vw_load.patient_code = '50006A02300001'
```

Pero quiero hacer una ordenación por el campo time. Al usar la cláusula `DISTINCT` y meter al final de la consulta `ORDER BY name_campo DESC`, me sale el error de que los datos por los que quiero ordenar deben de aparecer en la lista del select.

`ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list LINE 6:  order by vw_load.time`

Buscando información encontré algo con
`DISTINCT ON` pero me da error.
Hice la prueba con una subconsulta, pero también me daba error.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (ROUND(vw_load.val::numeric,4) AS value), 
      vw_load.patient_code,  vw_load.time::DATE AS date 
  FROM vw_load 
  WHERE 
    vw_load.disease = 8 
  AND vw_load.time >= '2026-01-01' AND vw_load.time <= '2023-03-09'
  AND vw_load.patient_code = '50006A02300001' 
) 
ORDER BY vw_load.time
```

No se cual puede ser la mejor manera de hacer esto, que seguro que no es tan complicado.

Comment: Cómo intentaste la subconsulta?

Comment: Eh, por fa ve a [edit] y añade siempre las respuestas a los comentarios en la pregunta. Como ves, seguir el código acá es... complicado. Tampoco te vamos a responder en comentarios :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Y si ordenas la subconsulta Y luego al resultado le aplicas el DISTINCT? Además, ordenar por `vw_load.time` no va a funcionar por fuera de la subconsulta porque el resultado tiene cuatro columnas `value, patient_code,load_time,date` y ya no tiene en el FROM la tabla vw...

Entonces, podría ser algo como

```
WITH pepito AS (
    SELECT 
        ROUND(vw_load.val::numeric,4) AS load_value, 
        vw_load.patient_code, 
        vw_load.time::DATE AS date
    FROM 
        vw_load 
    WHERE 
        vw_load.disease = 8
    AND 
        vw_load.time >= '2023-01-01' AND vw_load.time <= '2023-03-09'
    AND 
        vw_load.patient_code = '50006A02300001'
    ORDER BY vw_load.time
)
SELECT DISTINCT load_value
FROM pepito;
```

Y como no me acuerdo, prefiero no usar `value` como nombre de columna pa evitar dolores de cabeza con palabras reservadas.

Y lo edité para usar CTE ;)

Comment: Me pedía un alias para el select de from, aún así `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "vw_load"
LINE 1: SELECT distinct vw_load.value`

Comment: Respuesta editada. Perdón

Comment: Correcto @Alfabravo,  ahora si que obtengo resultados. Me queda adaptarlo a mi código. Gracias.